# Using single label or single button to display the fontawesome icon and text in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, font-awesome

This is my label code:

```
labelReview.font=[UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:20]
labelReview.text=[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FAPencil];
labelBeen.font=[UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:20];
labelBeen.text=[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FACheck];
labelAdd.font=[UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:20];
labelAdd.text=[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FAPlus];
LabelIn.font=[UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:20];
LabelIn.text=[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FAInfo];
```

Here is my button code:

```
[barButton setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FABars] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[phoneButton setTitle:[NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FAPhone] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: You should add a question.

Comment: Containing a oneview,inside the view adding the 2 label that is one for fontawesome icon and another one display text,so my question is combained the content and icon to display the single label or single button

Comment: So you want two different font into one label?

Comment: No no,only one label using to display the text and fontawesome icon